# What's the Difference between EndEllipsis and WordEllipsis in TextFormatFlags enum?

Tags: c#, winforms, text-rendering

According to my understanding of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx), when using `TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis` the text should be trimmed to fit inside the display rectangle and replaced with an ellipsis:

> EndEllipsis   |   Removes the end of trimmed lines, and replaces them with an ellipsis.

When using `TextFormatFlags.WordEllipsis`, the text should be trimmed to the last word that fits inside the display rectangle, and add an ellipsis:

> WordEllipsis   |   Trims the line to the nearest word and an ellipsis is placed at the end of a trimmed line.

However, I can't seem to find any difference between these two.

Here is my test control's code:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "This it my text. It's long enough to get cut in display.";
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var flags = (this.IsWordEllipsis) ? TextFormatFlags.WordEllipsis : TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, e.ClipRectangle, this.ForeColor, flags);
    }

    private bool _IsWordEllipsis;

    public bool IsWordEllipsis
    {
        get { return _IsWordEllipsis; }
        set { _IsWordEllipsis = value; this.Invalidate(); }
    }
}
```

No matter what value I set the `IsWordEllipsis` property - the text is always rendered as
`This it my text. It's long eno...`.

Shouldn't using the `WordEllipsis` flag trim the displayed string to the last complete word?
(`This it my text. It's long ...`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally `TextRenderer.DrawText` calls [DrawText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) function

Corresponding flags are:

> **DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS**: Truncates any word that does not fit in the
>   rectangle and adds ellipses.
>
> **DT_END_ELLIPSIS** For displayed text, if the end of a string does not
>   fit in the rectangle, it is truncated and ellipses are added. If a
>   word that is not at the end of the string goes beyond the limits of
>   the rectangle, it is truncated without ellipses.

I have interpreted .NET documentation for `WordEllipsis` same way as you, but above sentence probably better explains what this option is supposed to do.

In case it is still unclear take a look at this simple example, which tries to render `var quote = "Not every thing that\n can be counted counts,\n and not everything that\n counts can be counted.";`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I probably should have thought about testing multiple rows strings myself.